# How to access Laravel's json response inside ajax success/error

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

How to access properties that have been returned from response()->json() method from laravel

My Controller :

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:xlsx|max:10000'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Please only upload valid Excel (.xlsx) file.'
        ], 422);
    }
```

Ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
    url : "{{ route('budgets.import') }}",
    method:'post',
    async: false,
    data :new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);

        Swal.fire(
            'Failed!',
            response.message,
            'error'
        );
    },
});
```

result i've got when i console.log(response.response.data.message):

> Uncaught TypeError: response.response is undefined

How can i access the "message" property ?

**UPDATE 1**

result i've got when i console.log(response):
[image: unreadable response]

**Update 2**

I tried to check the Network tab then found that the status is 500, although i passed in the controller 422,

[image: weird response status]

But when i click the response the content was :

```
Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse {#1387
  #data: "{"message":"Please only upload valid Excel (.xlsx) file."}"
  #callback: null
  #encodingOptions: 0
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag {#1386
    #computedCacheControl: array:2 [
      "no-cache" => true
      "private" => true
    ]
    #cookies: []
    #headerNames: array:3 [
      "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
      "date" => "Date"
      "content-type" => "Content-Type"
    ]
    #headers: array:3 [
      "cache-control" => array:1 [
        0 => "no-cache, private"
      ]
      "date" => array:1 [
        0 => "Wed, 19 Jan 2022 12:20:50 GMT"
      ]
      "content-type" => array:1 [
        0 => "application/json"
      ]
    ]
    #cacheControl: []
  }
  #content: "{"message":"Please only upload valid Excel (.xlsx) file."}"
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 422
  #statusText: "Unprocessable Content"
  #charset: null
  +original: array:1 [
    "message" => "Please only upload valid Excel (.xlsx) file."
  ]
  +exception: null
}
```

The "message" property was there, just couldn't access it in ajax call. And the most frustrating one is statusCode is true 422 , but in network tab it says 500

Comment: `response.response` doesn't exist. Why would you also try and access that twice?

Comment: @Repox ah, my bad, i edit the question

Comment: Do you include csrf_token in your formData? Just console.log(response.status), Is it 422 or 419. If it 422 `response.responseJSON`, It should get data response.

Comment: @Chando its weird that the status was 500 instead of 422, but when i click the network response tab, it says statusCode = 422, please check my update

Comment: In network tab click on it and previous it. It will show some error responding in preview.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
response.responseJSON.message
```

Comment: Resulting : response.responseJSON is undefined

Comment: can you provide result return by this in error section console.log(response);

Comment: i update in the question, please check

Comment: @owf I have tested your code with this solution. It works absolutely fine (Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: i tried your suggestion but still undefined i dont know why

Comment: @BiswajitBiswas finally solve it, turns out on my parent controller there were a dd(), so that is the problem, thanks for the help